# Destiny level 23 only one strike mission left that requires friends

Tags: destiny

I've been playing Destiny for a few weeks now, but am still nooby, I don't understand a lot of things, but I'm really confused on what I should do next as I can't do the misson that requires friends, help?

Comment: You should have some active quests on the quest tab in the menu. What to they say to do? If you go to the Tower, does that show any NPCs that want to talk to you?

Comment: You can do the strikes even without friends.  If the description says 'Matchmaking', you'll be joined with other random people trying to do the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

If by "I don't have friends" you mean you don't have PS Plus or Xbox Live, then you are out of luck.  You need those services to do almost everything in Destiny.

If by "I don't have friends" you mean you don't have a big friends list (or people who play Destiny), most activities have Matchmaking.  They are:

The Heroic Strike Playlist (you can get up to 390 light gear here)

The Level 42 Prison of Elders (NOT Challenge of Elders, you need to form your own team for that)

Any Crucible playlist except Trials of Osiris

Activities that you NEED to form your own team are:

Any of the 4 raids

Nightfall

Challenge of Elders

Trials of Osiris

Just select an activity that has Matchmaking (it will tell you so) and have at it.

If your quest(s) say that you need to do an activity in the non-Matchmaking list, there is always DestinyLFG http://destinylfg.com/ or the100 https://www.the100.io/.

Good luck.